# Console.log function to terminal in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Doing the following in node.js with express.js

```
const callFn = (param) => param;
console.log(callFn);
```

expecting to get:

`(param) => param`

instead, I get:

`[Function: callFn]`

How do I actually get the expected results?

Comment: @Ctac Thanks, but that doesn't seem related. If you know how to actually get the expected results, please post you solution, would be happy to see it.

Comment: @Ctac Of course I make it a function, but what makes you think I shouldn't be able to output the expression? JavaScript treat functions as first-class citizens.

Comment: Why do you expect logging a function object to give you the source code of the function?